# What is wrong with this Git rebasing attempt?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I am trying to learn how to work with Git "by the book". Working on a project with multiple developers, we share the same "origin" remote. I am developing my code in a working area which is apart from the local git repo.

Let's call my branch `br_ysap`. I made changes to my code and am trying to introduce these into my branch, and ultimately to the `master` branch. The remote `master` was updated since the last time I synced stuff up. So, I want to rebase my branch to teh current master, then apply my updates, commit and push.

Here's what I am doing and the response:

```
> git clone ...

> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

> git checkout br_ysap
Branch br_ysap set up to track remote branch br_ysap from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'br_ysap'

> git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: SOME-COMMIT-COMMENT
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       Main/Init.c
M       Main/Main.c
A       Service/Service_1.c
A       Service/Service_2.c
M       build_options.mk
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging build_options.mk
Auto-merging Service/Service_3.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Service/Service_3.c
Auto-merging Main/Main.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Main/Main.c
Auto-merging Main/Init.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Main/Init.c
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 SOME-COMMIT-COMMENT
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   c:/local_repo/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Sometime in the past, `Service_2.c` was renamed to `Service_3.c`.

Now, I get "conflict" messages on `Main.c`, `Init.c` and `Service_3.c`. Next thing, I am resolving the conflicts. Checking the current status:

```
> git status
rebase in progress; onto fcd827a
You are currently rebasing branch 'br_ysap' on 'fcd827a'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   build_options.mk

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   Main/Init.c
        both modified:   Main/Main.c
        both modified:   Service/Service_3.c
```

So, I now copy the 3 files from my working space onto the git directory (that's instead of using a merge tool and to introduce new updates into the code).

```
> cp ../dev-tree/Main/Init.c         Main/Init.c
> cp ../dev-tree/Main/Main.c         Main/Main.c
> cp ../dev-tree/Service/Service_3.c Service/Service_3.c
```

Following [this tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/), I then stage the files:

```
> git add Main/Init.c Main/Main.c Service/Service_3.c

> git status
rebase in progress; onto fcd827a
You are currently rebasing branch 'br_ysap' on 'fcd827a'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   Main/Init.c
        modified:   Service/Service_3.c
        modified:   build_options.mk
```

**Question 1: what happened to `Main/Main.c`? Why is it gone?**

Next, following the instructions, I continue the rebasing:

```
> git rebase --continue
Applying: SOME-COMMIT-COMMENT
Applying: SOME-COMMIT-COMMENT - review update
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       Main/Init.c
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging Main/Init.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Main/Init.c
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 SOME-COMMIT-COMMENT - review update
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   c:/local_repo/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

**Question 2: Why is `Main/Init.c` still conflicting? I have overwritten the file with my newer version?**

Checking status, copying file, adding and checking status:

```
> git status
rebase in progress; onto fcd827a
You are currently rebasing branch 'br_ysap' on 'fcd827a'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   Main/Init.c

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

> cp ../dev-tree/Main/Init.c Main/Init.c

> git add Main/Init.c

> git status
rebase in progress; onto fcd827a
You are currently rebasing branch 'br_ysap' on 'fcd827a'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Supposedly ready to finish the rebasing, no? Well:

```
> git rebase --continue
Applying: SOME-COMMIT-COMMENT - review update
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".

> git status
rebase in progress; onto fcd827a
You are currently rebasing branch 'br_ysap' on 'fcd827a'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

**Question 3: What gives???** No, I did not forget the `git add`, thank you.

When I try to commit and push the branch, nothing is done:

```
> git push origin br_ysap:br_ysap
Everything up-to-date
```

**Question 4: What is wrong with this rebasing process?**

---

**Update 1:** Following @torek's description, suggesting I am missing the final commit step, I tried to do a `rebase --skip`. Unfortunately, the result was unexpected and over whelming:

```
> git rebase --skip
Applying: ANOTHER_COMMENT
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
A       Application/App_3.c
M       CSP/Driver_1.h
M       CSP/Driver_1.c
A       CSP/Driver_2.h
M       CSP/Chip.h
M       Common/Con_1.c
M       Diags/Con_2.c
M       Diags/Makefile
M       Main/Init.c
M       Main/Main.c
M       Main/Makefile
M       OS/Makefile
A       Service/Service_4.h
A       Service/Service_5.h
A       Service/Service_2.c
<stdin>:592: trailing whitespace.
//   $Id$
<stdin>:122074: trailing whitespace.
#define SOME_MOACRO_1
<stdin>:123643: trailing whitespace.
#define SOME_MOACRO_2
<stdin>:128989: trailing whitespace.
#define SOME_MOACRO_3
<stdin>:134620: trailing whitespace.
#define SOME_MOACRO_4
warning: squelched 9 whitespace errors
warning: 14 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging Service/Service_3.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Service/Service_3.c
Auto-merging OS/Makefile
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in OS/Makefile
Auto-merging Main/Makefile
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Main/Makefile
Auto-merging Main/Main.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Main/Main.c
Auto-merging Main/Init.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Main/Init.c
Auto-merging Diags/Makefile
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Diags/Makefile
Auto-merging Diags/Con_2.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Diags/Con_2.c
Auto-merging Common/Con_1.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Common/Con_1.c
CONFLICT (modify/delete): Application/App_3.c deleted in HEAD and modified in ANOTHER_COMMENT Version ANOTHER_COMMENT of Application/App_3.c left in tree.
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0003 ANOTHER_COMMENT
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   c:/local_repo/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

---

**Update 2:** Before doing the `--skip` I copied the directory so I can experiment from the point before Update 1. So, changing to that copy, I tried to `commit --allow-empty` instead of the `--skip`. I keep finding myself in what seems as a dead-end:

```
> git commit --allow-empty -m "YET-MORE-COMMENT"
[detached HEAD 4dd9e38] YET-MORE-COMMENT

> git status
rebase in progress; onto fcd827a
You are currently rebasing branch 'br_ysap' on 'fcd827a'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

It looks like the branch was detached finally, but was not attached to `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Q1, what happened is that the `Main/Init.c` you copied in:

> `cp ../dev-tree/Main/Init.c         Main/Init.c`

(and then `git add`ed) matches the version in the tree you're rebasing onto.

Remember that `git rebase` works by getting onto an anonymous branch that grows from the `--onto` commit—this defaults to the branch tip you're rebasing to, in this case the tip of `master`—and then repeating a `git cherry-pick` of each commit in the set-of-commits-to-copy.  (The commits-to-copy are those listed by `git log master..br_ysap`, in this case.)

Your current commit (middle, or really start, of rebase) is a commit on the anonymous branch that `git rebase` is building.  I'll give the branch a name to make it easier to see.  Things look like this (I'm assuming a very short set of commits between the original base and the rebase, so the `master` section is probably too short, but the idea should be clear enough):

```
          A - B - C - ... - S  <-- br_ysap
        /
... - o - o - o - T   <-- master, rebase-temp
```

Here commit `T` ( the `T`ip of branch `master`), is what you're rebasing on-to.  The temporary branch *also* points to commit `T`.  The commit git is currently trying to copy (and failing) is commit `A`, which, when rebase tells git to cherry-pick it, says to change something in `Main/Init.c`, but git couldn't make that change.

(If you take the commit ID that's being applied when things hit a conflict—the ID of `A` here)—you can run `git show <commit-id>` to see the entire commit, or `git show <commit-id> -- Main/Init.c` to see what happened to the one file.  Git was unable to apply those changes to the tip of the anonymous branch, so it gave you a conflict error.)

You then replaced the work-tree file (which had the conflict markers and everything) with your `../dev-tree` file.  After you "git add"ed everything, you ran `git status`.  This compares the index—what you're about to commit—with the contents of the most recent commit, which is commit `T`.  If a file matches the file in `T`, `git status` says nothing.

At this point you ran `git rebase --continue`.  This makes a new commit, which git is proud to claim is Just As Good As Commit `A`<sup>1</sup> so we call it `A'`:

```
          A - B - C - ... - S  <-- br_ysap
        /
... - o - o - o - T   <-- master
                   \
                    A'   <-- rebase-temp
```

Git now continues on with `git cherry-pick`ing commit `B`, which works fine, no conflicts—you can see why if you `git show` the original `B` and look at what would be in `rebase-temp` at this point.  In any case now we have this:

```
          A - B - C - ... - S  <-- br_ysap
        /
... - o - o - o - T   <-- master
                   \
                    A' - B'   <-- rebase-temp
```

Now git tries to copy commit `C`.  If you `git show` this commit, you'll see that the cherry-pick is supposed to make some more new changes to `Main/Init.c`, but again, git can't make those changes: they don't fit.

So, git stops with a conflict.  You're supposed to now edit the file and fix it up, but presumably you can just copy and add your `../dev-tree` version again (which you do, so that's Q2 and Q3 taken care of).  Now you run `git rebase --continue` and you get your final complaint from git (which relates to Q4):

> `Applying: SOME-COMMIT-COMMENT - review update`
>   `No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?`

Take a close look at commit `C` again, as shown by `git show`.  I suspect it has changes *only* to `Main/Init.c`.<sup>2</sup>  Those changes don't *do* anything to commit `B'` because that one already has them in it: they're the final changes to make the version of `Main/Init.c` in commit `B` match the version of `Main/Init.c` in commit `T` (tip of `master`).

What this means is that all the changes you want are already in.  You can force a "no changes" commit with `git commit --allow-empty` if you want to keep the empty commit, but `git rebase` won't do that for you.  Rebase prefers for you to say `git rebase --skip-commit` to tell it that, gosh, nothing from commit `C` is required after all.  It will then move on to the remaining commits—who knows how many there are (you can find out!)—and, if all goes well throughout those, do its finishing-up job, which consists of moving the branch `br_ysap` so that it points to the tip-most commit it *did* make, which I'll assume here is `S'`:

```
          A - B - C - ... - S  [abandoned]
        /
... - o - o - o - T   <-- master
                   \
                    A' - B' - D' - ... - S'  <-- br_ysap
```

You did not do that "skip" step so the rebase is still in progress, and your branch label `br_ysap` still points to original commit `C`, not to copied commit `B'`.  Hence `git push origin br_ysap` finds nothing to push.

---

<sup>1</sup>Whether it *is* "just as good" depends on how good a job you did when you resolved the merge conflict.

<sup>2</sup>Another possibility is that it has changes to some other file(s) that match changes that git is able to detect are already present, vs the "merge base" at which the old `br_ysap` and `master` join.  I believe you would have seen the "Falling back to ... 3-way merge" message in this case, though.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. It seems to me that one needs a deeper knowledge of git and its terminology than what I had to really understand the answer. Most of the first read just flew above my head...

Comment: So, I gave it a second and third read, plus some "git help". Let's see if I understand. The process of rebasing involves the re-application of a change of past commits from `master` to `br_ysap`. This is done by discrete steps, working on every commit on the way. This is why it is possible for a file to conflict more than once in the process. Possibly, it can conflict at any stop in the route.

Comment: When doint a rebase, git stops at the conflicting commit. Then, when resolving the conflict, doing `--continue` moves on from the point where it stopped to the next past commit in the change.

After the first rebase command and manually copying `Main/Main.c`, the staged copy was actually identical to the copy in `master's` commit, which is why it was gone from the `modified` list. That makes sense.

Comment: As I mentioned abovem the file `Main/Init.c` conflicted twice along the way. I believe it was this file, and not `Main.c` that you related to in your answer.

Following your suggestion, I continued with `git rebase --skip`. Contrary to what I expected, I got an overwhelming list of changed files and conflicts. Please see the **Update 1** in the question body.

Comment: On a copy of the local repo, I tried finalizing with `git commit --allow-empty` instead of skipping. I got a message for supposedly detaching the branch, but checking status and then attempt to `rebase --continue` gets me back at where we were. See **Update 2** for details.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I wrote `Main/Main.c` everywhere but should have written `Main/Init.c` everywhere.  I'll take a look at the updates soon...

Comment: OK, it looks like I mis-guessed that you were only rebasing three commits; in fact there are at least four or more.  Also, it's not clear to me why you replaced three entire files to resolve a conflict in one file.  Note that when you are rebasing, you are copying one earlier commit at a time.  If you replace an intermediate version with a final version, you will usually wind up tripping over the rest of your changes, which are now trying to apply "change mid-stream version 0.3 into version 0.4" to "final version 1.0".  In any case, let me edit my answer a bit.

Comment: " it's not clear to me why you replaced three entire files to resolve a conflict in one file" - following this discussion I gained a better understanding of the rebase process. I think that I now understand why copying the final version is not the correct way to deal with these conflicts. You need to walk the rebase process one commit at a time and let the automatic mechanism to try and resolve the then-conflicting lines of code.

Comment: [cont...] Doing so incrementally, is the correct way to allow the rebase process to bring `br_ysap` to look as if it was branched from the tip of `master`, while keeping all the intermediate commits done for `br_ysap`. Naively one would think that it actually should create a commit point in `br_ysap` that includes the changes from `master`'s head, but this will eliminate the evolution of the branch. I guess that `--squash` hos this effect.

Comment: Yet, one thing is still not clear to me - why, at the end of the process I did, there are no updates to commit and no conflicts to resolve, yet the rebase process cannot be finished.

Comment: Typically the need to `--skip` one or more commits occurs because one of your commits (on the branch you're copying-from) was made to fix a problem in the  "main line" code (on the branch you're copying-to), but that same problem is already fixed in the same way in the "main line" code.  When you reach that commit, there's nothing left to fix.